# How to use "sudo su" in java command

Tags: java, ssh

I am trying to use sshxcute class to connect to my unix machine and kill zombie processes.But the below program hangs. Please help me out.

```
public class SSHexecute {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("stage2c7400.qa.com", "rmeena", "sample");
        // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a singleton SSHExec instance
        SSHExec ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
        // Connect to server
        ssh.connect();
        CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("sudo su -; ps -ef |grep defunct");

        //CustomTask sampleTask1 = new ExecCommand("ls -lrt");
        try {
            Result s = ssh.exec(sampleTask);
            System.out.println("************"+s.sysout+"***********");

            } catch (TaskExecFailException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        ssh.disconnect();

    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend running the Java program as root instead.

Comment: how would you enter your password?

Comment: In shell it works this way I log in with my user name and password and then give sudo su -. It doesn't ask fora passowrd

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo su`. You can just use `sudo ps -ef | grep defunct`. But still, in shell, it prompts for password to make sure you are authorized to sudo. Through ssh this could be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

i dunno ur environments  but..
try this one.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("sudo").start();
p.getOutputStream().write("su -; ps -ef | grep defaunct".getBytes());

p.getOutputStream().write("exit\n".getBytes());

p.getOutputStream().flush();

p.getOutputStream().close();
```

Comment: I am getting the follwowing error Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "getOutputStream", Identifier expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token ".", { expected

Comment: @ramya So you didn't copy this code correctly. Did you forget the `()`? NB `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

Comment: p.getOutputStream().write("su -; ps -ef | grep defaunct".getBytes()); ....DO I HAVE TO do any specific import?

Comment: @ramya The code in this question compiles. If yours doesn't, it isn't the code in this question.

Comment: @EJP could you please give me the complete piece of code